# Parallel Code CPU utilization issue

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Collections

let computation input =
  input|> Array.map (fun x-> sqrt(float x))|> ignore

let computation1 (input:int[]) =
  input|> Array.map (fun x-> Convert.ToString(x,2)) |> ignore


let abc p = 

        for i in 1..50000 do
            [|for i in 1..100000 -> i|]
            |> computation 

Parallel.For(0,100,fun x->abc 0) |>ignore
```

Hi,
In the above program if I run the application with "*computation()*" in "*abc()*" I see CPU Utilization of 70-80%.

But the same code with "*computation1()*" in "*abc()*", I see just 20% CPU Utilization and I see many (half of the cores) cores are idle.

Does anyone have idea for this behaviour?

My CPU Specifications:
Intel Xeon CPU @3.40Hz with Hyper threading enabled
Total Cores: 2 CPUs with 8 cores each = 16
Total Cores with HT = 2*16 = 32

Comment: 1 big difference - string is ref type, int is value type.  Cache locality and memory bandwidth is much better in the first one.

Comment: Stylistic point: any reason why you used Parallel.For rather than Array.Parallel.map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be pretty easy to find out with a profiler, but in this case the answer is rather obvious:

```
Convert.ToString
```

will throttle your performance considerably, making it memory-bound and (possibly even more importantly), heap/GC-bound.

`computation` is almost pure CPU-work. `computation1` uses the heap for every single step you do - that means frequent memory access (in fact, it can't even use CPU caches very well, though GC compaction offsets this a lot), and frequently allocating and collecting strings on the heap. The heap and the GC are pretty high performing, but millions/billions of strings per second are really pushing it. Most of the time, your code is suspended because the GC is running.

Comment: @luaan-Yes, I agree, it could be because of string reference type. Will it be ok if I create a pre-allocated reference types pool, if I wish to use reference types inside computation?

Comment: @Mahesh Sure, that's one approach to take. Another approach would be to avoid reference types entirely, or to use mutable types. This really depends a lot on what you're trying to do - but creating millions of instances of reference types in a loop is almost always a terrible idea. Do keep in mind that using object pools can be much trickier than it looks - you need to handle allocation and deallocation yourself, you'll have to consider multi-threading issues (the pool has to be thread-safe, and you must keep the discipline to never use the object after it was released etc.).

Comment: @luaan- agreed. mutable types? do you mean value types?

Comment: @Mahesh The opposite - when you already have value types, you don't really need the mutability (unless the value types are part of a reference type, of course). In a way, it's just an extension of the object pool concept, except that instead of having a generic Acquire-Release semantic, you'd have some other way of tying the reference types to the appropriate worker - for example, if you always have four threads, and you only need the ref type once per iteration, you could have a single instance per thread, which would be reused on that thread. This is easily done with locals, of course.